# Conditional invoking of a trigger

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have triggers on a table but I want to invoke them only when the table is altered by an application directly (.NET application) and not if it is altered because of some other stored proc which may be in same database or an another database.  Is there anything like ClientID or something which could help me distinguish and invoke trigger conditionally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger will always be invoked but obviously you can just put conditional logic in to `RETURN` if you don't want additional code to run.

A couple of functions which might help are `APP_NAME()` or `CONTEXT_INFO()`

Failing that you could try

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
WHERE session_id = @@SPID
```

to see if anything suitable is there.

Don't rely on these for security however as they are easily manipulable by the client.